# Wordpress Thesis 2 - empty content using Post Box

Tags: wordpress, is-empty, wordpress-thesis-theme

I'm using Thesis 2.1 on the new Wordpress website I'm developing and unfortunately I'm not able to see any content. I'm using the **Post Box -> Content** box to display content but nothing shows up. Other boxes like **Post Box ->Title** and **Post Box -> Excerpt** work fine, everything just the content.

It doesn't matter whether I try a Post, Page, or Custom Post, always the same case. Everything else seem to work okay.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Post Box won't work fully unless it's inside a WP Loop box.  Somehow the excerpt still works, but many of the other variables will come up empty, like content, author, date, etc.

Comment: Appreciate it bro!